# Do electromagnetic fields exist at the scale of the Planck length?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

The Planck length is considered to be the smallest possible measurement length in physical terms.  At this extremely small length, does the Maxwellian formalism of electromagnetism no longer apply?

Comment: None of our physics including Maxwel's EM, and more importantly the quantum theory of it, QED, nor its unification with the weak force, nor the Standard Model of particle physics which includes those plus the strong force, nor gravity, hold at the Planckian scale. There's Quantum Gravity and other work that's researching what happens there. Ps/I didn't downvote, but yo want want to read some and modify your question to not get more downvotes.

Comment: So all of the presently known laws of physics break down at the Planck length, is that what you're saying?  If so, surely there must be other laws of physics that apply at this scale.  Are you telling me that no one presently knows that they are?  Do electromagnetic waves still travel at the "speed of light" when their wavelength is the Planck length?

Comment: You are rightly shocked. Just keep in mind that Planck sizes are about 15 orders of magnitude form what we can probe today. Similarly for the energy scale. And people of course are both working various theories, and also working through extensions of what we do know to make some guesses of what's coming. So in Quantum gravity there's string theory and loop quantum gravity that deal with what happens with spacetime, but it's just two theories and there is no observational data on it. For extensions of what's known it's Beyond the Standard Model, and there's other hypothesis.

Comment: See some popular books on the topic like Brian Greene's The Fabric of the Cosmos. But remember it's more hypothesis than proof. And yes, even the constant speed of light is in doubt at those scales since spacetime may be different. Lorentz invariance may also not hold then or even break somewhat before. Particles at those scales are not electrons and quarks and so on, maybe more like strings or loops or other things in higher dimensional spacetime and at those scales we might see the othe dimensions. So, yes, be shocked, what we know is called sometimes a low energy approximation to reality

Comment: Bob Bee, thank you for your honest comments.  Since an electromagnetic wave apparently cannot exist with a wavelength of the Planck length, the Planck length thus constitutes an upper limit for the electromagnetic frequency spectrum.  This being the case, what do physicists regard as the highest frequency/shortest wavelength EM waves that do have a possibility of existing in physics as we know it today (even if we do not yet have the capability to detect them)?